# How to use float without flipping floated item and changing in source order? Is this possible?

Tags: css, xhtml, css-float

See this example to understand

http://jsbin.com/ocewu

[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/212/8042227539.png](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/212/8042227539.png)

This is code of example

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #000; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #fff; }

div {width:300px;height:42px;border:2px solid red}
a{border:2px solid blue;padding:10px}
div a {float:right}
#div2 a {float:left}

</style>
</head>
<body>

I need positioning in right like this

<p>div a {float:right}</p>

<div >
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>
</div>

but element order like this without changing in HTML code

<div id="div2">
  <a>A</a>
  <a>B</a>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the requirement here?  You're forced to use float: right, or you can only change the CSS, but not the HTML?

Comment: when more element will come i want to force them all in right but when i use float:right it flips the order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### One Additional Div to the Mix?

If you can edit your CMS template, wrap them in one additional div, and float that div: http://jsbin.com/esoqe

```
div.els { float:right }

<div class="main"> 
  <div class="els"> 
    <a>A</a> 
    <a>B</a> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

#### JQuery Fixes *Everything*

If you can't make even a minor change like that to the Code, you could re-order these with Javascript once the page finishes loading.

```
$(function(){
  // create previous hierarchy
  $("div.main").wrapInner("<div class='els'></div>");
});
```

#### Absolute Positions - Yuck.

The last option (and I shudder to even call it an option) is to absolutely position each of the divs, being sure to set their parent container position to `relative`*. This option would require you to return and make changes to your .css file each time you add a new box, which is unfortunate.

<sup>* If you cannot set rules for their parent, or a parent of the same dimensions, then this option is removed from the table as absolute positioning will default to the viewport, which isn't what you want.</sup>

Comment: i alredy mentioned i can't edit html code is CMS generated. i don't have access to html code. my problem is when more element will come in div like "c" i want to force them all in right but when i use float:right it flips the order.

Comment: Jitendra, you can edit your CMS, and add that DIV, or you could also consider re-arranging them with Javascript once the page loads.

Comment: can we get this thing using any Absolute positioning method? I'm just asking if it's posible. I can't edit html and can't use javascript.

Comment: Yes, but it would require updating your `.css` file each time you add a box. Less effort involved in writing a script with javascript, or adding a div to your CMS output.

Comment: tell me Absolute positioning method if there is no other way. boxes are fixed. nothing will add or remove. or if it will happen i will change in css.

Comment: Does the parent DIV has a `className` or `ID`?

Comment: @yes every element has class and ID.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the HTML for that particular area?

Comment: Absolute positioning should just require a "position: relative" and a fixed width on the red box above, then give fixed widths and "position: absolute" to both of the blue boxes, set their tops to 0px and their left (or right) coordinates as needed.

Comment: Without the help of an extra div like Jonathan says, it isn't possible to keep the order (this is: if you can't edit html or javascript). If you do it with absolute positioning, please keep in mind that you set the parent element to relative, so the fixed links will stick to the parent element and not any other relative positioned element.

Comment: I know it's not possible but it's the best answer with all other options. I selectin this as an answer. and I like this type of detailed answer. Thanks @Jonathan Sampson

Answer (score 1):

Good alternative for ordering html elements is to convert them to inline blocks (if they aren't already) and then use text-alignment for wrapping element:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element-to-align">Align me</div>
  <div class="element-to-align">Align me</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
  text-align:right;
}

.element-to-align{
  text-align: left; // if you want still align text to left within the element.
  display: inline-block;
}
```

In your case **a** tag inline-block by default so there is no need to assign display:inline-block to it. Common elements like **span** and **img** are also inline-blocks by default.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. See: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=28936

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you are not flipping the order of A and B? When you float something right with text the order gets inverted.